# bash: node-v0.10.20-linux-x64/bin/node: No such file or directory

Tags: heroku

I was following [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-deploying-slugs) to release Programmatically code to Heroku and i was able to deploy the slug on heroku with this results:

```
{ addon_plan_names: [],
  app:
   { id: 'a247a2f8-fa1a-48ea-8b89-96b1f924093a',
     name: 'arcane-plateau-99175' },
  created_at: '2019-10-29T04:25:17Z',
  description: 'Deploy',
  status: 'succeeded',
  id: 'e12da0fd-c12a-4872-b580-49ea49259863',
  slug: { id: '1b72b657-e2cf-49e2-8e0a-94ec94de8559' },
  updated_at: '2019-10-29T04:25:17Z',
  user:
   { email: '******@gmail.com',
     id: '63bb3b9a-6349-44e4-8cb4-ba54d6ee7b34' },
  version: 3,
  current: true,
  output_stream_url: null }
```

I also created ./app folder
and added the 2 files:

```
http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.20/node-v0.10.20-linux-x64.tar.gz
web.js
```

[image]

then i converted the  "app" folder into slug.tgz file. Once i deploy the slug, i get the error:

```
2019-10-29T04:32:20.182896+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-10-29T04:32:20.492003+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node-v0.10.20-linux-x64/bin/node web.js`
2019-10-29T04:32:22.807892+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2019-10-29T04:32:22.896147+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-10-29T04:32:22.733421+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: node-v0.10.20-linux-x64/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

**What i am doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you're looking at allows you to create slugs (a container image) from scratch.
When doing that, you need to include node within the slug by yourself.

You may be looking for the Heroku documentation on [building and releasing using the Platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-and-release-using-the-api) instead.

This API will let you create builds with your code base. You will pass a tar containing your uncompiled source code to Heroku, and they will build it using [buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks). In your case, the [node](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs) one.

Comment: Thanks Damien for the directions, i will do it today later :)